# Get Image Bounding box from Image of Page with Python

Tags: python

Say I have an image of a book page (something similar to what is pictured below) and want to generate a bounding box for the central image (outlined in green). How might I do this with python? I've tried the normal edge detection route but have found it to be too slow and that it picks up too many edges within the actual image of interest. Meanwhile libraries like [detecto](https://pypi.org/project/detecto/) attempt to look for objects within the images rather than just detect some rectangular image. I have about 100 of these that I'd like to process and generate bounding boxes for.

100 is too few for me too want to train any kind of AI model, but too many to just do manually. Any thoughts on an approach?

[image]

Comment: 100 are not too many. My guess is that you could do it faster if you do it manually than if you try to create a script to do it with the same accuracy. Unless what you actually want is to learn how to solve the problem with programming, but in that case I do not have any recommendation.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a procedural, progromattic answer.